# How to create LifeRay theme by modifity classic theme?

Tags: liferay

I want to create custom liferay theme. In tutorials says that i gonna copy directories from classic theme to `_diff` folder of my theme. But i cant find classic theme folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created liferay-theme project with maven (if you're using maven) like this

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=liferay-theme-archetype \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.liferay.maven.archetypes \
-DarchetypeVersion=6.1.0 \
-DartifactId=sample-theme \
-DgroupId=com.liferay.sample \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

then just look into ./target/liferay-theme/work folder. Ah, there it is.

No need to actually *compile* it - Liferay merges whatever changes your theme is supposed to apply to classic theme during `theme-merge` phase of `liferay` maven plugin. It works much like a maven overlay, so you can just leave out every file in classic theme you do not intend on changing.

Comment: But i work in Eclipse. I copy folders from theme directory in `_diff` directory but its no help me.

Comment: do you use ANT Liferay SDK?

Answer (score 0):

There is no classic theme folder. Simply make copies of the /css /images /js and /templates folder from /docroot and put them into the /_diffs folder.

Then you start making all your edits in the /_diffs folder copies. When the project is built via ANT, it overwrites the files in the root /docroot folders you copied.

If you want to embed images in a theme, put them in /docroot/_diffs/images/custom and use this code.

```
<img src="$themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages()/custom/logo.png" id="splash_logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new theme in liferay without modifying the default liferay theme.

Use the following link to create a theme.

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035353731-Introduction-to-Creating-a-Theme

This will be useful to somebody searching for custom liferay themes.

And goto the settings icon on right top corner in admin account and click on `look-and-feel` -> 
Define a specific look and feel for this page. -> Change current theme